# Wrong type after type casting using asInstanceOf Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to type cast from the super type java.io.Serializable to List[String] or List[List[String]]. I used asInstanceOf method as seen below but the type remains as the java.io.Serializable.

Input Data:

```
val singleList = "apple:orange"

val nestedList = "apple:orange;James:Mike"

val size = 8
```

Functions:

```
def x(s:String): List[String] = {

    s.split(":").toList
}

def s (s1: String) : List[ List[ String ]] = {

   s1.split(";").toList.map(x=> x.split(":").toList)
}


val f = if(size <= 8) {

       x(singleList).asInstanceOf[List[String]]

     } else{

        s(nestedList).asInstanceOf[List[List[String]]]
      }
```

Desired Output type:

List[String] or List[List[String]]

Thanks

Comment: Type of *what* "remains" `java.io.Serializable`, and what did you expect to get instead?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, I want to return List[String] or List[List[String]] and this depends on size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, "`List[String] or List[List[String]]`" is not a valid type. You have the following choices:

- wrap it into `Either[List[String], List[List[String]]]`,
- explicitly ascribe `f` to be of type `List[_]`
- just accept that the most specific type that can be inferred is `List[java.io.Serializable]`, and work with that.

You could of course define `or` to be an infix operator that is just an alias for `Either`:

```
import util.{Either, Left, Right}

type or[A, B] = Either[A, B]

val f: List[String] or List[List[String]] = {
  if (size <= 8) Left(x(singleList))
  else Right(s(nestedList))
}
```

but it does not have any significant advantages over using `Either` directly.

If you decide to use `Either` / `or`, you will have to work with it in all subsequent steps too. For example, here is how you would format `f` as single line or multi-line table:

```
def formatAsTable(t: List[String] or List[List[String]]): String = t match {
  case Left(singleLine) => singleLine.mkString(",")
  case Right(multiLine) => multiLine.map(_.mkString(",")).mkString("\n")
}

println(formatAsTable(f))
```

Comment: Can you show me how to use Either please, I have not used it before.

Answer (score 0):

You can't conditionally return one of two different types like that. Consider using [`Either`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/util/Either.html) instead:

```
val f: Either[List[String], List[List[String]]] = if (size <= 8) {
  Left(x(singleList))
} else{
   Right(s(nestedList))
}
```

Comment: how can I access the value of f?